# CSS is not applied correctly when using Backbone.Marionette region

Tags: css, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

I'm new to Backbone.Marionette and now I'm developing my first app with this framework.

The problem that I'm struggling now: css is not applied correctly when I'm using regions with my views. To be more specific: I have a CompositeView which renders a slider with pictures (using roundabout jQuery plugin). Everything was fine until I've tried to use it with region.

I added a region `{ sliderContainer: "#sliderContainer"}` to my application and than called `show(view)` on it. Now it is not rendered correctly (I guess, the styles which were defined on the root view div element with `id="greatSlider"` are not applied). I thought that problem is in extra div that I added for region, but after I removed the region, and made sliderContainer an el of my view also moving greatSlider to the template, I got everything working ok again. Any thoughts how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was my mistake in selector no problems with regions anymore.